# How to define a scope to service-worker cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, browser-cache

I created a CRA project enabling service-worker. The webapp run on the same domain of the backend services. When I open a new page requesting a static source (like excel file) from the backend services, the browser show my webapp.

Example:

- **webapp URL**:  *http://domain/backend-path/[index.html]*
- **backend service URL**: *http://domain/backend-path/excel (return a file)*

If from webapp URL inside react I open a link in another page requesting for backend service URL **the browser returns me the cached webapp**.

I need to define a 'cache scope' or is there another solution?